# how to restrict apc to only one installation of drupal on virtual server

Tags: drupal, apache2, settings, apc

I have one virtual server with 2 installations of drupal. One is for testing purposes. Is it possible to restrict usage of APC to certain directories only, so the testing page won't eat the same amount of resources as production site? My files are installed on server like this:

```
 data/web/mydomain.com/web - I want to use apc here. 
 data/web/mydomain/sub/test - I do not want to use apc.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question: **Is it possible to restrict usage of APC to certain directories only?** *Yes.*

Use the [`apc.filters`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters) directive in your `apc.ini` file:

> A comma-separated list of POSIX extended regular expressions. If any
>   pattern matches the source filename, the file will not be cached. Note
>   that the filename used for matching is the one passed to
>   include/require, not the absolute path. If the first character of the
>   expression is a + then the expression will be additive in the sense
>   that any files matched by the expression will be cached, and if the
>   first character is a - then anything matched will not be cached. The -
>   case is the default, so it can be left off.

So, to exclude the testing directory, add the following to your apc.ini file and restart apache:

`apc.filters = "-/data/web/mydomain/sub/test/.*"`

Comment: Hi, how is it possible to disable apc on certain url path?

Comment: If the url represents an actual path on the system, then the above method would work. But if you're using Drupal to create URL aliases, that wouldn't be possible. For example, two drupal nodes might have the following aliases. Node 1: /articles/article1; Node 2: /stories/story1. But those are really just path aliases and in reality the same php scripts are being used to generate both pages (save a unique node-type template).

Comment: Hi, I would like to restrict admin pages from being cached.

Comment: Then you will have to determine which php scripts are specifically used to generate admin pages and manually exclude those (they don't all live in one directory).

Answer (score 2):

Also, at sub-site level in drupal you can achieve this by adding following line in settings.php:

ini_set('apc.enabled', 1); // 1 to enable & 0 to disable apc for a sub-site.

Comment: Hi, Do you mean to install apc on server as usual and in drupal settings.php installed on subsite just add ini_set('apc.enabled', 0) to turn it off for that installation? that would be great

Comment: yes, please try that because i setup different  php ini settings for subsites like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have APC disabled in your global php.ini by default and enable it exclusively in a custom php.ini for the document root in question. This would definitely depend upon your httpd/php configuration, I.e. DSO/suPHp